# UI-select dropdown option not show above panel body

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ui-select

I have a panel with fixed height with overflow set to auto. Inside that panel I am using ui-select.

On-clicking/opening the select box it is getting hidden behind the panel footer and user has to scroll down to view. Is it possible to get the ui-select display outside of the box having fixed height with overflow set.

```
         <div class="panel-body" style="height:100px;overflow:auto;">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <ui-select ng-model="person.selected" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="min-width: 300px;">
                <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a person in the list or search his name/age...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
                <ui-select-choices repeat="person in people | propsFilter: {name: $select.search, age: $select.search}">
                <div ng-bind-html="person.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
                  <small>             email: {{person.email}}             age:             
                     <span ng-bind-html="''+person.age | highlight: $select.search"></span>
                  </small>
              </ui-select-choices>
              </ui-select>
        </div>
```

[PLUNKER LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/elvnwneP0Z7avTAXDkbN?p=preview)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `overflow: visible` on `.panel-body` like in this **[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/Pmk63g4biDqj2EW5BJyO?p=preview)**

Comment: it works.. but then removes the scroll bar for the given height, i want scrollbar to be in place

Comment: Same thing, the scrollbar should be visible.